# How to serve Allure Report without automatically starting the browser

Tags: allure

When i start the [allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/), the server always attempts to start the browser:

```
$ /home/allure/allure-2.3.4/bin/allure serve target/allure-results -p 5012
    Generating report to temp directory...
    Report successfully generated to /tmp/779851636804605067/allure-report
    Starting web server...
    2017-08-21 17:51:00.271:INFO::main: Logging initialized @3082ms
    Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The BROWSE action is not supported on the current platform!
            at java.awt.Desktop.checkActionSupport(Desktop.java:225)
            at java.awt.Desktop.browse(Desktop.java:381)
            at io.qameta.allure.Commands.openBrowser(Commands.java:207)
            at io.qameta.allure.Commands.open(Commands.java:135)
            at io.qameta.allure.Commands.serve(Commands.java:119)
            at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:136)
            at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
            at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)
    2017-08-21 17:51:06.387:WARN:oejsh.ResourceHandler:qtp1928301845-20: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    2017-08-21 17:51:06.388:WARN:oejsh.ResourceHandler:qtp1928301845-15: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
```

The problem is not in the error, but in the launch, I don't need to start it on this host.
How do I start the allure server without starting the browser?

Comment: `allure serve` should be only used as a tool to watch results on local machine. In case you need to host the report the right way is generate the report in some folder and configure nginx to serve files from such folder

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry, can you help me one more, which directory need to serve? in case i use `/home/project-name/allure-report` . I don't see Steps and there are no groupings on Story. That is, annotations are not caught. I see the allure is being given /target/allure-reults. Perhaps in Nginx, there is need something else to mention in addition to `/home/project/allure-report`

Comment: directory you generate report into (`/home/project/allure-report` in your case)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the docker container Allure Docker Service, recognize the results automatically and update the reports without doing anything:
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service